# Mysql, partitioning not working on date range

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to partition a table, this is its structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `username` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `event` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `obj_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `inline` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `meta` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date`),
  KEY `event` (`event`),
  KEY `obj_id` (`obj_id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `user_date` (`username`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
 PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date))
(PARTITION actions_0 VALUES LESS THAN (1209592800) ENGINE = InnoDB, # 2008-05-01
 PARTITION actions_images_1 VALUES LESS THAN (1212271200) ENGINE = InnoDB, # 2008-06-01
 [...]
 PARTITION actions_67 VALUES LESS THAN (1388530800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION actions_68 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

now, it seems to be fine when I select for a specific date:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM `actions` WHERE `date` = '2008-05-04 16:13:15' ;

+----+-------------+----------------+------------------
| id | select_type | table          | partitions       
+----+-------------+----------------+------------------
|  1 | SIMPLE      | actions        | actions_1
```

but if I do this query:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM `actions` WHERE `date` > '2008-05-04 16:13:15' AND `date` < '2008-05-05 16:13:15';
```

Mysql scans for all the actions_N tables, what am I doing wrong?
this is the first time I'm using partitions but I followed the manual and I can't find where I got wrong.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well, it's a mysql bug
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28928

Answer (score 0):

The use of partitioning columns employing date or time types other than DATE or DATETIME is not supported with RANGE COLUMNS.

DATE and DATETIME. Columns using other data types relating to dates or times are not supported as partitioning columns.