# MySQL Range Partitioning DATE() Not Working

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I'm working on the optimization of MySQL query these days, one of the issues I've encountered is **`DATE()` maybe not working for the table partitioned by date range**.

---

Here is the sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE `testing_db` (
  `date_time` date NOT NULL,
  `id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date_time`,`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`date_time`,`id`),
  KEY `idx_date_time` (`date_time`),
  KEY `idx_id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (to_days(`date_time`))
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2021-01-01')),
 PARTITION p2021_01 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2021-01-31')),
 PARTITION p2021_02 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2021-02-28')),
 PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

Statement with `DATE()`:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT date_time, id FROM testing_db WHERE date_time = '2021-02-25';
```

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  testing_db  p2021_02    ref PRIMARY,unique,idx_date_time,idx_id PRIMARY 3   const   1   100.00  Using index
```

Statement without `DATE()`:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT date_time, id FROM testing_db WHERE DATE(date_time) = '2021-02-25';
```

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  testing_db  p0,p2021_01,p2021_02,future index       idx_date_time   3       1   100.00  Using where; Using index
```

---

Comparing two explanations, obviously **the statement with `DATE()` scans all partitions while the statement without `DATE()` doesn't**. Its impact may be significant in a large table.

I've researched similar issues, but it seems they are not relevant to this case:

- [Official Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date), `DATE()` extracts the date part of the date or datetime.
- [Mysql, partitioning not working on date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258293/mysql-partitioning-not-working-on-date-range)
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28928

Could you help figure it out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Didn't you invert the results of EXPLAIN?

Comment: @Alaindeseine May I know what do you mean?

Comment: Because you wrote "Statement without DATE(): " and the statement use DATE()

Comment: Do not use `WHERE DATE(date_time) = '2021-02-25`. Use `WHERE date_time >= '2021-02-25' AND date_time < '2021-02-26';` instead. PS. `date_time` is DATE datatype column, hence `DATE(date_time)` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the DATE() function in your WHERE clause negates the use of any relevant index which causes a full table scan. The full table scan will need to read from all partitions.

In your example you are applying the DATE() function to a column of type DATE, so it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

- `INDEX(date_time)` is unnecessary because there are two other indexes starting with that column.
- A `PRIMARY KEY` is (in MySQL) a `UNIQUE` key.  So your `UNIQUE(datetime, id)` is redundant.
- Usually is is unwise to *start* any index with the partition key (`date_time`).
- `WHERE DATE(date_time) = ...` is not "sargable".  That is, no indexing of `date_time` can be used when hiding a column in a function (`DATE()`).  (This is the main problem that you are asking about.)
- Instead of using `DATE()`, use a range, such as:

  ```
  WHERE date_time >= '2021-02-26'
    AND date_time  < '2021-02-26' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ```
- Based on the above comments, plus other things, just these two indexes would be better:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY(id, date_time),
  INDEX(date_time, id)
  ```
- Please don't call it `date_time` when it is only a `DATE`.  My comments work for either datatype.  The `DATE()` function is never needed around a column of datatype `DATE` nor a string that looks like a date.
- Your partition definitions put the last day of each month in the 'wrong' partition'.
- Be aware that `PARTITIONing` rarely helps with performance.  I discuss that further in [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/Pagination)